# JavaScript Only FadeIn Function

Tags: javascript, decimal, floating-point-conversion

```
  fadeIn:function(speed,till){
          speed = speed !== undefined ? speed : 400;
          speed = typeof speed === 'number'  ? speed : speed == "slow" ? 600 : speed == "fast" ? 200 : speed !== 'slow' || speed!== 'fast' ? 400 : 400;
          var opc = window.getComputedStyle(this[0]).opacity;
          var element = this[0];
          var add = 100 / speed;
          till = till !== undefined ? till : 1;
          element.style.display="block";
          var timer = (function  a() {
           if (opc >= till ){         
            element.style.opacity = 1;              
            clearInterval(timer);
            return false;
            }
            if(browser[3] == 'MSIE' && Number(browser[4]) < 9 ){
            add = 10000 / speed;
            element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity="' + (opc+ add) + '")';
            }
            element.style.opacity = opc;
            opc = opc + add; // code here where addition starts
            setTimeout(a, 50);
          })(); 
    },
```

Now the function above will not run its course correctly. As JavaScript does not correctly add floating decimals. So I've tried many ways...

```
 opc = (opc * 100) + (add * 100) / 100;
```

Also tried a close hack as this gives me my decimal number the above gives me a whole number no matter what really.

```
 opc = "."+parseInt((opc * 100) + (add * 100) / 100,10);
```

Though I believe whats wrong with the above is that it turns into a string and well just doesn't cut. So the question is how do I increment decimals as this is very necessary.

**EXAMPLE**

```
  0.001 - 0.002 - 0.003 - 0.004 etc
```

Comment: I wonder what you need "correct" floating-point maths for in something simple as this animation?

Comment: You might want to add `add` to `opc` instead of `speed`, for a start, or else the timer loop will exit before anything could be changed.
My advice: indent your code, drop the hacker thingies like this[0], give meaningful names to your variables, get the horrible IE8- detection out of the way and come back with something we can actually try to debug without hurting our eyes. There are a million reasons your code may fail, and your assumption it must be JavaScript at fault does not add to your credibility.

Comment: Some of it was just small errors when explaining the code. Sorry guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is adding floating point numbers fine.
Probably one of your operands is not a floating point number.

Quote from a JS book:
*JavaScript has a single number type. Internally, it is represented as 64-bit floating
point, the same as Java’s double. Unlike most other programming languages, there is
no separate integer type, so 1 and 1.0 are the same value.*

I would try to debug the code and then see which values are strings (or not numbers), and then parse them using the [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) function.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I'll go back to the drawing board and debug my code and see what happens. I was initially going to try this with time settings and use that as the starting point. This was my third try as I've never actually tried to replucate the `.fadeIn()` of jQuery, I'm just now learning JavaScript (Vanilla) to raise my knowledge of this all. Be back soon mate

Comment: Perfect mate, by using the parseFloat function I now cut alot of my coding out. Now is parseFloat compatible with IE<9 ?

Comment: @EasyBB Not 100% sure but it should be as it's a very very basic function. You can just try it out if you have an old IE at hand.

Comment: @EasyBB http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/d5hbbd4z%28v=vs.94%29.aspx See the Requirements section.